# Huge swf files, reducing file size?

Tags: flash, filesize

They contain a few simple graphics, a short actionscript, and a wav file each of around 4mb. And the resulting swf weighs fully 29-45mb. For a while I thought it was the wav files that made up most of the weight, but it's turned out they're not especially large.

Not sure why, the actionscript is pretty short, and there aren't many or large graphics in the files, in other words they don't have that much content. The WAV files themselves are around 4mb each - one per file. Any advice as to what could cause these huge file sizes of 45mb each, based on that?

Answer (score 0):

I usually first look at the compression of the graphic elements Im using.  I try to optimize the size of the images in photoshop or whatever I use BEFORE I bring them in actually, then I use flash import / bitmap related settings to get best compression without loosing too much quality. Next I'd try to also optimize the audio files - instead of wavs, I'd go with mp3 files actually and lastly, when you export, you can set the quality to around 80 or 90.  good luck.

Comment: well, thanks, it's just that not even the original psd files for the graphics weig anywhere near up to 45mb, nor the original wav files, so not sure it has to do with basic optimization. also the images are png and don't use flash's jpg deblocking. I'll try to post back if i figure it out.

Comment: if you have dropbox or something and need an extra pair of eyes to look over it I'd be glad to help.  Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks, but I finally just compressed the wav files outside of flash (with itunes) and it seems to have reduced the file size significantly so far. Confusing it is that the wav files were only 4 gigs to begin with, wonder why flash made them so much bigger, oh well.

Comment: Actually, that was wishful thinking on my part. The files are now twice as large, 80-127 MB! That's after optimizing the sound files outside flash. I therefore chose 'raw' under flash's compression settings, because the sound files are now optimized before flash. Don't know what to do, this seems crazy, optimizing has increased the file size.